# The block following this 'let' is unfinished, F# error

Tags: f#

I've been trying to create a code in F# that can read text via another file, however I keep seeing a

> The block following this 'let' is unfinished. Every code block is an expression and must have a result

on the

```
let a = line.Split delim
```

,I looked it up and thought it was an indentation error but that didn't fix that. Any advice?

```
[<EntryPoint>]

let main argv =

let delim = ','

use stream = new StreamReader @"final.txt"
let line = stream.Readline()
let a = line.Split delim

|>Seq.map System.Int32.Parse
|>Seq.toArray

printfn "Orignal numbers: %A" a
printfn "Ordered numbers: %A" (oddEven a)

0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing indentation (and misspelled a thing or two). Anything that you want to be part of a `let` block has to be indented one level. Here's your code properly formatted:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let delim = ','

    use stream = new StreamReader @"final.txt"
    let line = stream.ReadLine()
    let a =
        line.Split delim
        |> Seq.map System.Int32.Parse
        |> Seq.toArray

    printfn "Orignal numbers: %A" a
    printfn "Ordered numbers: %A" (oddEven a)

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot!